# <script>-tag in jsp is restructured

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, cytoscape-web

I'm developing a spring-mvc application and i want to include javascript in one jsp.
In other posts I found this solution for including js-files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/AC_OETags.min.js" />" />
```

but when I run the application it is transformed to this:

```
<script json2.min.js"="" js="" resources="" src="<c:url value=" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Can anybody tell me why and how to avoid this?

Comment: What do you mean by "transformed"? Are you including the taglib directive? Is it being processed by the JSP processor? Also, IIRC script tags should always use the long form (`<script ...></script>`) but I could be wrong about that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the el-expression

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="${c:url('/resources/js/AC_OETags.min.js')}" />
```

Regards